# Sobrecarga de operadores + en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo estas dos funciones que realizan una sobrecarga sobre una clase Contador que tiene como atributos privados `int max_(valor max)` y `int val_(valor dado)`. El enunciado dice esto:

- El operador `+` devuelve un contador cuyo valor es la suma entre un objeto de tipo Contador y un entero. Ej: c+10 (el valor máximo del contador devuelto por la suma debe ser el valor máximo de c).
- El operador + que devuelve un contador con la suma entre un entero y uno de tipo Contador. Ej: 10+c (el valor máximo del contador devuelto por la suma debe ser el valor máximo de c).

Mis dudas son: qué diferencia hay entre ambos apartados, por que una función es friend y la otra no, cual de las funciones se corresponde con el apartado a y cual con la b y por que. Las funciones hacen lo que tienen que hacer, es solo error de conceptos por mi parte.

Les dejo aquí el código:

```
Contador operator+(int a){
    if(max_<(a+val_)){
        val_=max_;
    }
    else{
        val_+=a;
    }
    return *this;
}
friend Contador operator+(int a,Contador &c){
    if(c.getM()<(a+c.getV())){
        c.val_=c.max_;
    }
    else{
        c.setV(a+c.getV());
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los operadores (igual que cualquier otro tipo de función) pueden definirse en dos contextos diferentes:

1. **Función miembro**: El operador se define dentro del objeto:

   ```
   struct Objeto
   {
       Objeto operator+( ... ) { ... }
   };
   ```
2. **Función libre**: El operador se define fuera del objeto:

   ```
   struct Objeto
   {
       ...
   };

   Objeto operator+( ... ) { ... }
   ```

Cuando el operador es una función miembro sólo recibe un parámetro, ya que el otro parámetro de la operación es el propio objeto, por este motivo la instancia del objeto siempre está a la izquierda del operador:

```
struct Objeto
{
    Objeto operator+(int) { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
    Objeto o;

    // Correcto, llama a Objeto::operator+
    auto resultado1 = o + 1;
    /* Incorrecto, no existe ningún operador +
       que tome int a la izquierda y Objeto a la derecha. */
    auto resultado2 = 1 + o;

    return 0;
}
```

Para poder poner el objeto a la derecha del operador, se necesita una función libre. La función libre recibe dos parámetros: el primero será el objeto a la izquierda del operador y el segundo el objeto a la derecha:

```
struct Objeto
{
    Objeto operator+(int) { return {}; }
};

Objeto operator+(int, Objeto) { return {}; }

int main()
{
    Objeto o;

    // Correcto, llama a Objeto::operator+
    auto resultado1 = o + 1;
    // Correcto, llama a la función libre operator+(int, Objeto).
    auto resultado2 = 1 + o;

    return 0;
}
```

Pero las funciones libres tienen un "*problema*", dado que no forman parte de ningún objeto, no pueden acceder a los datos privados de ningún objeto.

```
struct Objeto
{
    Objeto(int valor) : valor{valor} {}
    Objeto operator+(int numero) { return {numero + valor}; }
private:
    int valor = 0;
};

Objeto operator+(int numero, Objeto objeto) { return {numero + objeto.valor}; }
//       Error!!! Objeto::valor es innacesible (miembro privado) ---> ~~~~~
```

Este "*problema*" se soluciona marcando la función como amiga, de esta manera podrá tener acceso a los miembros privados del objeto:

```
struct Objeto
{
    Objeto(int valor) : valor{valor} {}
    Objeto operator+(int numero) { return {numero + valor}; }
    friend Objeto operator+(int numero, Objeto objeto);
//  ~~~~~~ <--- Declaración de función amiga
private:
    int valor = 0;
};

// Definición de función, no es necesario decir que es 'friend'.
Objeto operator+(int numero, Objeto objeto) { return {numero + objeto.valor}; }
```